.Net MAUI Page Inheritance - How To Display Both Pages' Contents?
Throughout the development of my app, I found that many pages will have a very similar content to one another, with only one difference amongst them. In order to prevent duplicated code and, consequently, more maintenance, I decided to make all of them inherit from a single base page.
However, no matter what I did, the content would always be displayed incorrectly. Instead of showing the content of both the base page and the child page, only the child page would be displayed.
I made a test project to keep experimenting until I found a solution, but to no avail. Here's what I have so far:
Base Page .xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             Title="MainPage">

  <VerticalStackLayout>
    
    <!-- The child page will need access to this label as well -->
    <Label x:Name="LabelMain" Text="MainPage content."/>
    
    <!-- This is where the child page's content should be -->
    <ContentPresenter/>
    
  </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>

Base Page .cs:
namespace MauiApp1
{
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
    // The child will need access to this variable.
    protected int test = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}

Child Page .xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:MainPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.NewPage1"
             Title="NewPage1">

  <Label Text="NewPage1 content."/>
</local:MainPage>

Child Page .cs:
namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class NewPage1 : MainPage
{
    public NewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

The Result:
the child page's content overriding the base page
As you can see, the child page (NewPage1) has completely overridden the base page's (MainPage) content.
My question is: how can I make the content of both pages be displayed in the manner that I desire, which is the child page replacing only the designated <ContentPresenter/> tag?
EDIT: Forgot to mention that the child page will require access to the base page's views and variables too.

Since you're already looking into ContentPresenter, consider having common PageView which is a subclass of ContentView. i.e. <ContentPage><PageView><!-- your custom stuff here --></PageView></ContentPage>

@StephenQuan how would that work, exactly? You mean creating a new ContentView called PageView and placing the content there?

Yes pretty much. Would you like me to post it in an answer? Mind, you, having reread your question, seems the only customization you're doing is customizing the TitleView. There's nothing else in your VerticalStackLayout so it isn't really needed.

@StephenQuan I've just tested it and it ends up having the same effect as the pages, where the content inside the PageView is overwritten by whatever is within its opening and closing tags. Am I doing something wrong? Also, I do need to keep the MainPage's original content together with the NewPage1 so that I can have the MainPage's header labels along with the NewPage1's text.

You need to understand the difference between ControlTemplate and Content. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-9.0

Ah, I see. So ContentPresenter can only be used in Control Templates? I thought it'd be possible to use them in pages as well.

Here's how to implement a reusable BasePage with a custom property
<!-- BasePage.xaml -->
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MyMauiDemo.BasePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="{TemplateBinding MainText}" />
                <ContentPresenter />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>

// BasePage.xaml.cs
namespace MyMauiDemo;
public partial class BasePage: ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MainTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MainText), typeof(string), typeof(BasePage), default(string));
    public string MainText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MainTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(MainTextProperty, value);
    }
    public BasePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

And here's how you can use BasePage:
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<local:BasePage
    x:Class="MyMauiDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyMauiDemo"
    TitlePage="MainPage"
    MainText="HELLO WORLD">
    <Label Text="MainPage content." />
</local:BasePage>


References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-9.0


I see. Thanks! Would it be possible to do the same for other type of content as well, however? The string bindable property works well for the example I've shown, but what if I decide to make a more complex solution where the base page would have its own content and then I'd want the child page's content to be presented within it, as I had envisioned originally?

It was demoed. see the 2nd Label. It is based on your example.

Ah yes, of course. My apologies, I completely overlooked it. Thank you!
